# Pygame Bullets (python 3.2.5)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing a python coding project for school and I need to code a pygame that shoots bullets from a specific blit.

I tried using this code,

```
if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):      
        if (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):       
            screen.blit(projectile,(projectilex,projectiley))
```

The projectile's `x` coordinate is equal to the player's `x` coordinate that it shoots from. So like:

```
projectilex = playerx
```

It only appears on the screen for 1 second then disappears. I need to it start at the player's `x` and increase it's `y` value until it hits the top of the screen, then disappears. Any help?

**Note: I have to use python 3.2.5 and I cannot upgrade to newer versions.**

Answer (score 1):

`screen.blit` only displays something for the duration of a single frame. You need to draw the bullet each frame. Use separate variables to track the bullet's X and Y position and whether to display the bullet. E.g.,

```
if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):      
    if (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):       
        show_projectile = True
        projectile_x = player_x
        projectile_y = player_y
# ...
if show_projectile:
    screen.blit(projectile, (projectile_x, projectile_y))
```